# Как в qt в функции connect передать параметры от сигнала слоту (новый вариант)

Tags: c++, qt5

Было вот так, все работало:

```
QObject::connect(&counter, SIGNAL(counterChanged(int)), &lbl, SLOT(setNum(int)));
```

Теперь не знаю, как можно передать параметр от `counterChanged` в `setNum` в новой версии `connect`:

```
QObject::connect(&counter, &Counter::counterChanged, &lbl, &QLabel::setNum);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот способ, с которым я раньше работал и всё было нормально:

```
QObject::connect(&counter, static_cast<void (Counter::*)(int)>(&Counter::counterChanged), &lbl, &QLabel::setNum);
```

То есть нужно привести функцию к требуемому типу. Но в документации недавно появился [новый способ](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload), но я его не проверял. Этот способ требует включения C++14.

```
QObject::connect(&counter, QOverload<int>::of(&Counter::counterChanged), &lbl, &QLabel::setNum);
```

Comment: Спасибо, эту информацию я находил, правда не находит функций ни QOverload, ни qOverload. Какие заголовочные файлы необходимо подключить чтобы работали эти функции?

Comment: А все понял эти фишки появились в Qt 5.7 у меня Qt 5.5

Comment: Первый способ будет работать и на Qt 5.5.

Comment: Да хорошо я понял, я про QOverload имел ввиду